# Speed up MySql query time with multiple conditional joins

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join

There are 3 tables, persontbl1, persontbl2 (each 7500 rows) and schedule (~3000 active schedules i.e. schedule.status = 0). Person tables contain data for the same persons as one to one relationship and INNER join between two takes less than a second. And schedule table contains data about persons to be interviewed and not all persons have schedules in schedule table. With Left join query instantly takes around 45 seconds, which is causing all sorts of issues.

```
SELECT persontbl1._CREATION_DATE, persontbl2._TOP_LEVEL_AURI, 
       persontbl2.RESP_CNIC, persontbl2.RESP_CNIC_NAME, 
       persontbl1.MOB_NUMBER1, persontbl1.MOB_NUMBER2, 
       schedule.id, schedule.call_datetime, schedule.enum_id,
       schedule.enum_change, schedule.status
FROM persontbl1
INNER JOIN persontbl2 ON (persontbl2._TOP_LEVEL_AURI = persontbl1._URI)
                      AND (AGR_CONTACT=1)
LEFT JOIN SCHEDULE ON (schedule.survey_id = persontbl1._URI)
                  AND (SCHEDULE.status=0)
                  AND (DATE(SCHEDULE.call_datetime) <= CURDATE())   
ORDER BY schedule.call_datetime IS NULL DESC, persontbl1._CREATION_DATE ASC
```

Here is the explain for query:

[image]

Schedule Table structure:

[image]

Schedule Table indexes:

[image]

Please let me know if any further information is required.

Thanks.

Edit: Added fully qualified table names and their columns.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Also add the tables definitions.

Comment: You should qualify all the column names with table aliases, so we know where the columns are coming from.

Comment: @GordonLinoff table names are added.

Comment: @Dorvalla query optimization, since i am a beginner at MySQL, would really like to have some expert opinion on the matter.

Comment: what is your `SCHEDULE.call_datetime` type?

Comment: @Alex its 'datetime'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just replace this line:

```
AND (DATE(SCHEDULE.call_datetime) <= CURDATE())
```

to this one:

```
AND SCHEDULE.call_datetime <= '2015-04-18 00:00:00'
```

so mysql will not call 2 functions per every record but will use static constant `'2015-04-18 00:00:00'`.

So you can just try for performance improvements if your query is:

```
SELECT persontbl1._CREATION_DATE, persontbl2._TOP_LEVEL_AURI, 
       persontbl2.RESP_CNIC, persontbl2.RESP_CNIC_NAME, 
       persontbl1.MOB_NUMBER1, persontbl1.MOB_NUMBER2, 
       schedule.id, schedule.call_datetime, schedule.enum_id,
       schedule.enum_change, schedule.status
FROM persontbl1
INNER JOIN persontbl2 ON (persontbl2._TOP_LEVEL_AURI = persontbl1._URI)
                      AND (AGR_CONTACT=1)
LEFT JOIN SCHEDULE ON (schedule.survey_id = persontbl1._URI)
                  AND (SCHEDULE.status=0)
                  AND (SCHEDULE.call_datetime <= '2015-02-01 00:00:00')   
ORDER BY schedule.call_datetime IS NULL DESC, persontbl1._CREATION_DATE ASC
```

**EDIT 1** So you said without `LEFT JOIN` part it was fast enough, so you can try then:

```
SELECT persontbl1._CREATION_DATE, persontbl2._TOP_LEVEL_AURI, 
       persontbl2.RESP_CNIC, persontbl2.RESP_CNIC_NAME, 
       persontbl1.MOB_NUMBER1, persontbl1.MOB_NUMBER2, 
       s.id, s.call_datetime, s.enum_id,
       s.enum_change, s.status
FROM persontbl1
INNER JOIN persontbl2 ON (persontbl2._TOP_LEVEL_AURI = persontbl1._URI)
                      AND (AGR_CONTACT=1)
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT *
   FROM SCHEDULE
   WHERE status=0
     AND call_datetime <= '2015-02-01 00:00:00'  
  ) s
ON s.survey_id = persontbl1._URI

ORDER BY s.call_datetime IS NULL DESC, persontbl1._CREATION_DATE ASC
```

Comment: with right date time provided e.g. (today) '2015-04-19 00:00:00' query took 42 seconds, this didn't made any difference :(

Comment: @Ayub and could you provide schedule table structure please? do you have indexes on `call_datetime` ans `status`?

Comment: it says 'Every derived table must have its own alias', i am also updating the question with structure ...

Comment: oops... fixed...was typo at the end of  `'2015-02-01 00:00:00' `

Comment: now it says Unknown column 's.id' in 'field list', would you like to give it a try using teamviewer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75604/discussion-between-ayub-and-alex).

Comment: Alex I ended up changing the structure of the database, but your query had best time so far 20secs

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `AGR_CONTACT` comes from `p1`.  This is the query you want to optimize:

```
SELECT p1._CREATION_DATE, _TOP_LEVEL_AURI, RESP_CNIC, RESP_CNIC_NAME,
       MOB_NUMBER1, MOB_NUMBER2, 
       s.id, s.call_datetime, s.enum_id, s.enum_change, s.status
FROM persontbl1 p1 INNER JOIN
     persontbl2 p2
     ON (p2._TOP_LEVEL_AURI = p1._URI) AND (p1.AGR_CONTACT = 1) LEFT JOIN
     SCHEDULE s
     ON (s.survey_id = p1._URI) AND
     (s.status = 0) AND
     (DATE(s.call_datetime) <= CURDATE())   
ORDER BY s.call_datetime IS NULL DESC, p1._CREATION_DATE ASC;
```

The best indexes for this query are:  `persontbl2(agr_contact)`, `persontbl1(_TOP_LEVEL_AURI, _uri)`, and `schedule(survey_id, status, call_datime)`.

The use of `date()` around the date time is not recommended.  In general, that precludes the use of indexes.  However, in this case, you have a `left join`, so it doesn't make a difference.  That column is not being used for filtering anyway.  The index on `schedule` is only for covering the `on` clause.

Comment: Gordon, AGR_CONTACT comes from the first table (p1). I modified your query accordingly and checked the indexes as well, it still takes 40 seconds, roughly 2-3 seconds better performance wise